# Update a Specific Hash Key when Values are Hashes

Tags: ruby, hash, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri to count the occurrences of different class attributes that appear on a website. To do this I am implementing a breadth-first search and every time I encounter a new class attribute I want to store it's class name as a key and the number of occurrences as a value (so a hash where the values are hashes). As an example:

```
{"media"=>{:occurrences=>1, :id => uniqueID},
"wrapper"=>{:occurrences=>3, :id => uniqueID},
"container"=>{:occurrences=>3, :id => uniqueID}}
```

And every that same class attribute is encountered I want to find that same hash and increment its occurrence key.

```
allHash = {}
uniqueID = 0
if allHash.key?(descendent["class"]) 
   allHash.map do |key, v| #increment occurrences key if class is encountered during search
     if key.to_s == descendent["class"]
         v[:occurrences] += 1 
     end
   end
else #make a new hash key if class name is not in hash
  uniqueID += 1
  allHash[descendent["class"]] = {id: uniqueID, occurrences: 1}; 
end
```

So the final hash might change to this at the end of the search:

```
{"media"=>{:occurrences=>1, :id => uniqueID},
"wrapper"=>{:occurrences=>5, :id => uniqueID},
"container"=>{:occurrences=>10, :id => uniqueID}
"content"=>{:occurrences=>1, :id => uniqueID}}
```

The code I have above fails to increment the occurrences however. How can I implement this?

Comment: Two asides. 1: one of Ruby's conventions is to use [snake-case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) for the naming of methods and variables (e.g., `all_hash` rather than `allHash`). You don't have to follow that convention but 99%+ of Rubiests do. 2: when you give an example, make it succinct but complete, with all elements valid Ruby objects (as you have), show the desired result as a Ruby object and assign a variable to each input object (e.g., `h = {  "media"=>...}`) so that readers can refer to those variables in answers and comments without having to define them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a bit of a simpler approach:

```
unique_id = 0
hash = Hash.new {|h, k| h[k] = {id: (unique_id += 1), occurrences: 0} }

descendent_classes.each do |descendent_class|
  hash[descendent_class][:occurrences] += 1
end
```

Result (with `descendent_classes = ["a", "a", "b"]`):

```
irb(main):031:0> hash
=> {"a"=>{:id=>1, :occurrences=>2}, "b"=>{:id=>2, :occurrences=>1}}
```